# Laravel Open a route in a modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.1

Following code shows a button that when I click routes me to a page where I see the post.

```
<a href="{{ route('post.show',$post->id) }}" 
   class="btn btn-info btn-xs" 
   role="button" 
   data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Show
</a>
```

What should I do show the content of the route in a modal dialog window?
I was able to figure ut how to use the bootstrap data-toggles to show a modal dialog, but not able to figure out how I can get the routes html content to show in the modal.

Comment: To clarify, what do you want is that by clicking in a link, Laravel redirects you to a view in which a modal is open with the content at the first, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to get it done. But please don't solve it via iframe.

If there should be only text in the modal, put an empty modal into your main layout and fill it with variables.

If there is a form or something that really should come from an other view, get it with ajax and put it in the modal.

---

### **EDIT**

AJAX solution:

Put the `CSRF token` into your DOM, so you can access it from everywhere. You could need it for `POST` requests. Laravel does not accept POST requests without this token by default.

Also put an empty modal into your `body`. Later you will fill it with `HTML` which you'll get with `AJAX`.

`main.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <div class="modal fade" id="dynamic-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Modify your HTML:

```
<button data-path="{{ route('post.show',$post->id) }}" 
   class="btn btn-info btn-xs load-ajax-modal" 
   role="button" 
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dynamic-modal">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Show
</button>
```

---

Set up the header for your AJAX requests

`custom.js`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Look for the click event on your button, get HTML from the requested url (`data-path` attribute) and put it into your modal-body.

```
$('.load-ajax-modal').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : $(this).data('path'),

        success: function(result) {
            $('#dynamic-modal div.modal-body').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

---

All of this is not tested and is just a concept ;)

---

**2. EDIT**

If you want to replace more than the modal body, you also have different ways to solve it:

1. Return `JSON` Object with/for different content
2. Return that `DOM-Node`, that you need and place it into your raw modal.

Comment: I like the idea of ajax, but I don't know much about it. Can you nudge me in right direction to look for how I can call a laravel route using jquery ajax call.

Comment: do you have jquery included? Or are you using another js-lib?

Comment: I have jquery included, but how to call a laravel route from ajax is what I didn't understand.

Comment: Your code worked out of the box. Only thing I didn't understand is ajaxSetup with `'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')`. Why is this required?

Comment: one more thing is my modal has modal-content with modal-header, modal-body and model-footer. Even though you are just updating modal-body in ajax, header and footer goes missing. any clue why is that?

Comment: `$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')` grabs the content from your `meta-tag`which contains the `CSRF-Token`, `$.ajaxSetup()` puts this token into your `AJAX` header. Without that code you would not be able to `POST` data to the Server. Check http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Ps. if that solved your problem, please mark it so ;)

Comment: Yes, I marked it, thanks. Please answer my last question (in the comment above) as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could use data attributes to do this;
My example is (in Laravel 5.4 with jquery 3): i have a list of users and at the end of each user record i have 2 buttons edit & delete; on delete i have to open a modal that shows a message, informing me of  deletion or deactivation (with routes to each user action); so i have done it like so:

- listing case in td element:

  ```
              <span class="pull-right cursor-pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUserDeletion"
                    data-user="{{ json_encode(
                          [
                              'user_id' => $fos_user->id,
                              'first_name' => $fos_user->first_name,
                              'last_name' => $fos_user->last_name,
                              'user_deletion_route' => route('user.delete', ['id' => $fos_user->id]),
                              'user_deactivation_route' => route('user.deactivate', ['id' => $fos_user->id]),
                          ]
                      ) }}" onclick="displayCurrentUserInfo(this);">
                  <img src="{{ asset('images/svg_icons/trash-16.svg') }}" alt="">
              </span>
  ```
- modal markup:

  ```
     <div class="modal-body popup-user-deletion">
          <div>@lang('translations.user_deletion_modal_explanation')</div><br>
          <div>
              <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" data-user-delete onclick='return confirm("{{ __('translations.user_delete_message') }}");'>
                  <img src="{{ asset('images/svg_icons/trash-16.svg') }}" alt="" class="svg_image">&nbsp;
                  @lang('translations.user_deletion_button')
              </a>
          </div><br>
          <div>@lang('translations.user_deletion_or')</div><br>

          <a href="#" class="deactivate" data-user-deactivate>@lang('translations.user_deactivation_button')</a>
      </div>
  ```
- js for it:

  ```
          // function used for displaying info in user deletion popup
      function displayCurrentUserInfo($this) {
          var $current_user = $($this);
          var $current_user_data = $current_user.data('user');

          $('[data-user-name]').html("").html("-&nbsp;" + $current_user_data.first_name + " " + $current_user_data.last_name + "&nbsp;-");
          $('[data-user-delete]').attr("href", "").attr("href", $current_user_data.user_deletion_route);
          $('[data-user-deactivate]').attr("href", "").attr('href', $current_user_data.user_deactivation_route);
      }
  ```

And i recommend defining globally the transmission of CSRF token to all requests with js, by putting the following code in resources/assets/js/app.js like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}});
```

And of course, you have to also have included a meta tag with the token in your  section of your app:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```